# Dresden Files Cooperative Card Game promotional/exclusive event cards

Tags: dresden-files

For the Dresden Files Cooperative Card Game, I think I read once that there were about 2 or 3 promotional cards given out at a convention or in a Loot Crate type box. Maybe had a female character on them? Forgot where I saw some for sale.
Can't seem to find the cards searching Google.

Anyone know what the names were or where they were given out?

Comment: Unless you have more information on where these were handed out, they'd likely be impossible to find.  Evil Hat is a fairly small company though, so I don't think they have a whole lot of freebies to hand out.  My best educated guess is that they could have been Harry or Susan variant cards, or one of the other stretch goals that were added later in the Kickstarter.  Those are all available in their store, to my knowledge.

Answer (score 4):

At the time of this writing, [BoardGameGeek's list of expansions](https://boardgamegeek.com/boardgame/187273/dresden-files-cooperative-card-game/expansions) for the game show that the following are the only promotional cards that have been released:

### Mouse & Variants

> An Evil Hat webstore exclusive for the Dresden Files Cooperative Card Game! Bring Harry's faithful companion Mouse (with a dash of Mister) into the game with this character deck packet. Also includes 2 variant cards for Harry's deck and 3 variant cards for Susan's deck to add a little variety to your play.
>
> –[Store page](https://www.evilhat.com/store/index.php?main_page=product_info&cPath=80&products_id=318&zenid=7dm1glu7jljvrlojntujtfgev5)

### Ra Crossover

> An Evil Hat webstore exclusive for the Dresden Files Cooperative Card Game — and a crossover with Greater Than Games' Sentinels Comics universe! The sun god Ra steps into a new avatar in the Dresdenverse with this fully playable character deck. When one supernatural fire-slinger isn't enough, it's time to call down the flames!
>
> –[Store page](https://www.evilhat.com/store/index.php?main_page=product_info&cPath=80&products_id=319&zenid=7dm1glu7jljvrlojntujtfgev5)

Both of these were also available as Kickstarter promotional items before being made available on the web store.

It sounds to me like the Mouse & Variants pack is the one you are thinking of with a female character on them, given that it contains 3 variant cards for Susan's deck.